# NullPointerException when Linear layout click event on fragment

Tags: android

I have a fragment and I want to show a dialog when I click a Linear Layout, but I am getting a NullPointer Exception when I try to find LinearLayout of idioma, here is my code, somebody can help me? Thanks

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {




    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.preferencias, container, false);


    LinearLayout idioma_layout= (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.idioma_layout);
    idioma_layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v)
     {

         AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle(R.string.language_prompt);
            builder.setItems(R.array.languages, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    // Do something with the selection
                    switch (item) {
                        case 0:
                         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Español", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         savePreferences("idioma","es");

                         break;
                        case 1:
                          Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Inglés", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                          savePreferences("idioma","en");

                          break;

                    }
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

     } 
    }); 

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);


    return view;
```

Comment: By "NullPonter" you mean "NullPointerException" I suppose? If so, post the stack trace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `getView()` method inside `onCreateView()`. The view hasn't been created yet and `getView()` returns null in this case.

You already have to view in this method though (you just inflated it into your `view` variable):

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.preferencias, container, false);
LinearLayout idioma_layout= (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.idioma_layout);
```